# Docker push --all-tags does not work in the pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to push my image that have been built in the pipeline to the Docker registry and I have two tags on my image (`latest` and `commit hash`), but when using the command `docker push --all-tags registry.gitlab.com/group/image-name`, it does not work and I get this error:

> unknown flag: --all-tags

I am using docker with the latest version and GitLab CI/CD stage definition is like this

```
Build Docker Image:
  stage: Build Docker Image
  image: docker:stable
  needs: ["Build & Test App"]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login "$CI_REGISTRY" -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" .
    - docker tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - docker push --all-tags "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
```

When I tried it on my local machine, it seems like this flag is known and it works. Do you know, what could be the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: the --all-tags option was added in Docker 20.10, so your pipeline is probably running an earlier version.

Comment: You pipeline runs on a gitlab-runner which uses a Docker image, not on your local machine. Check the version of Docker running on your gitlab-runner.

Answer (score 5):

For use `--all-tags` use the `docker:latest` image

Comment: It would be better to specify which version of Docker to use, in this case whichever is the first one that supports --all-tags

Comment: `-a/--all-tags` was added by docker 20.10.0 (2020-12-08)

Comment: You can't specify a tag like "latest" when using `--all-tags`